# Add multiple apps to single project in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am using firebase notifications to my project, my firebase project is handling android and iOS projects, what I am getting notifications are same to android and iOS.  I was added Android app to project, I want add IOS app to same project but am not able add my IOS app to project,

this is the screenshot before one

[image]

now I am trying to add another app to project but am not able to add the project, I want add IOS app to the same project. How to add multiple apps to single project?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you have to create two projects, one for ios and the other is for android. But both contains same app identifier.

Comment: aBilal17 both are different project

Comment: how to add same app identifier

Comment: What is the error showing when you have tried to add second app in a project?

Comment: when I select add iOS app nothing is happening

Comment: when I am select web app adding its working fine

Comment: Try by logging out and logging in again and then try

Comment: you can add apps in the same project as many as you want. this is unfamiliar behavior try contacting firebase support.

Comment: I just tried and can add another iOS app to my project (that already has multiple iOS apps in it). If you're having problems adding an iOS app to your project, check the developer console of your browser for error messages. If those don't help you resolve the problem, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you very much for replay, problem is resolved when am login with  another system, I can add multiple app to the project

Comment: Note the “Getting Started with Firebase" video at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup advises against setting up several unrelated apps in the same project because it may lead to “tears and heartache” (2:20 mark). What those "tears and heartache" are I can't figure out. In my project I have 6 iOS apps in the same Google Firebase Project so I did not have issues adding multiple apps, but these apps also have not shipped.